# Attempting to write breadcrumbs for octopress and failing

Tags: github, split, breadcrumbs, liquid

Here is my attempt so far. I realise that there may be other ways to do this.

But why is my call to split failing?

```
{% capture path %}
  {{ page.url | remove: ".html" | remove_first:"/" }}
{% endcapture %}
{% capture breadcrumbs %}
  {{ path | split:'/' }}
{% endcapture %}
{% for crumb in breadcrumbs %}
  {{ crumb }} &#187; 
{% endfor %}
```

I am uploading this to github and just getting nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never been able to get `split` to work properly either, but [breadcrumbs are still possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9633517/1256624). The following is adapted from my code in that answer (note the section that should be modified in the `if` statement and that this is the readable version and doesn't work precisely as expected).

```
{% capture url_parts %} {{ page.url | remove: "/index.html" | replace:'/'," " }}{% endcapture %}
{% capture num_parts %}{{ url_parts | number_of_words }}{% endcapture %}
{% assign previous="" %}
{% if num_parts == "0" %}
  <Handle being at the top of the site (i.e. "site.com/") here>
{% else %}
 {% for unused in page.content limit:num_parts %}
  {% capture first_word %}{{ url_parts | truncatewords:1 | remove:"&hellip;"}}{% endcapture %}
  {{ first_word }} &#187;
  {% capture url_parts %}{{ url_parts | remove_first:first_word }}{% endcapture %}
 {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

If the user is at `/a/b/c.html` this will print `a » b » c »`, if they are at `/a/b/` (or equivalently `/a/b/index.html`) it will just print `a » b »`.

At least, it will be close to that: for a Markdown file there are too many newlines between each time `first_word` is printed, so they are considered separate paragraphs and the output will be (this isn't a problem in an HTML file, but then more tags are needed to make it work properly):

```
a »

b »

c »
```

This can be solved by putting the whole for loop on one line (this is the code that should be used):

```
{% capture url_parts %} {{ page.url | remove: "/index.html" | replace:'/'," " }}{% endcapture %}
{% capture num_parts %}{{ url_parts | number_of_words }}{% endcapture %}
{% assign previous="" %}
{% if num_parts == "0" %}
  <Handle being at the top of the site (i.e. "site.com/") here>
{% else %}
 {% for unused in page.content limit:num_parts %}{% capture first_word %}{{ url_parts | truncatewords:1 | remove:"..."}}{% endcapture %}{{ first_word }} &#187;{% capture url_parts %}{{ url_parts | remove_first:first_word }}{% endcapture %}{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

(NB. the `page.content` in the for loop is just to give something to iterate over, the magic is done by the `limit:num_parts`. However, this means that if `page.content` has fewer paragraphs than `num_parts` not all breadcrumbs will appear, if this is likely one might define a site variable in `_config.yml` like `breadcrumb_list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]` and use `site.breadcrumb_list` as the placeholder instead of `page.content`. (Lifted from my other answer.))

[Here is an example](http://huonw.github.io/bread/crumbs/example/) (it doesn't use precisely the same code as above, but it's just a few little modifications, and it is in an HTML file, so the problem with new lines creating paragraphs is not there).

Comment: It was actually your answer on the other thread which got me thinking about this in the first place. Thanks for the further explanation on your method. I'm hoping someone is gonna explain what is wrong with the split method though, as that seems to be the more natural way of approaching the problem.

Comment: I don't suppose you have an example on the web to see it in action?

Comment: @Toby, yep I do now, see the end of the question :)