# Output link to "parent page"?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a collection `_colletion`. In there is a file `_collection/path/topic.md` and a folder `_collection/path/topic/` that includes lots of `.md` files with content. The permalinks for these files are `/path/topic` and `/path/topic/file-x` - so a parent page with a folder with the same name with multiple random pages in it.

Now I want to output a link to `/path/topic` in all these `.md` files with the title of `topic.md` as link text:

```
---
title: This is the page title defined in topic.md
---
```

should become
    `<a href="/path/topic">This is the page title defined in topic.md</a>`

How do I do that most easily?

Can I somehow access the folder name `topic` of the `.md` files and use this to read `topic.md` and output it's `title` and also generate a link to it?

Comment: Isn't 'topic' part of the page.url?

Comment: Yes, `file-x.md` would get `/path/topic/file-x` as its `page.url`. I was hoping to somehow be able to go from this to `topic` and then to the `title` and URL of `topic.md` so I can link there.

Comment: It would have been easier if topic.md was called index.md...

Comment: And placed in `/topic/` folder? I would be fine with that if its URL stays `/path/topic` (without trailing slash should work or at least be redirected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current manual "solution" (or workaround):

Add a `parent` entry to the frontmatter of all pages in `/topic/` that contains the title and relative URL for the `topic.md`:

```
parent: ['Topic Title', '../topic']
```

In the template of the pages:

```
{% if page.parent %}
  <p>« <a href="{{ page.parent[1] }}">{{ page.parent[0] }}</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

Works, but of course duplicates this information n times and has to be maintained manually.

Comment: Not very DRY, but a solution with an acceptable build time.

Answer (score 2):

During discussion in the comments on my question and the other answers I noticed that what I wanted to build was actually a very common thing: A breadcrumb navigation! Just a very "small" one, with only one level.

With this newfound knowledge I could google "breadcrumb" plugins for Jekyll:

This solution uses the path of the page to extract the "crumbs":

- https://www.mikestowe.com/blog/2017/08/adding-breadcrumbs-in-jekyll.php

It uses the folder name for the link text.

Another similar implementation:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9633517/252627

Another one:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37448941/252627

So no `title` link text in all of these.

---

This solution actually reads the page `title`, but can also read `breadcrumb` frontmatter from the pages, and uses these as link text:

- https://github.com/comsysto/jekyll-breadcrumb-for-github-pages/
- https://comsysto.com/blog-post/automatic-breadcrumb-for-jekyll-on-github-pages
- https://gist.github.com/csgruenebe/8f7beef9858c1b8625d6

This one might be a valid solution.

---

There are also real plugins (that unfortunately don't work with Github Pages):

- https://github.com/git-no/jekyll-breadcrumbs

Answer (score 1):

How about this (option 1)?

```
{% assign pageurl_array = page.url | split: "/" %}
{% assign path = pageurl_array[0] %}
{% assign topic = pageurl_array[1] %}
<p>« <a href="{{ path }}/{{ topic }}/{{ topic }}.html">
  {{ topic | capitalize | replace: "-", " " }}
</a></p>
```

If you do not mind crazy build times, do this (option 2):

```
{% assign pageurl_array = page.url | split: "/" %}
{% assign path = pageurl_array[0] %}
{% assign topic = pageurl_array[1] %}
{% capture parent_url %}{{ path }}/{{ topic }}/{{ topic }}.html{% endcapture %}
<p>« <a href="{{ parent_url }}">
  {% for i in site.pages %}
    {% if i.url == parent_url %}
      {{ i.title }}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</a></p>
```

I would go for the first option (much faster) and use this javascript to get the capitals and special characters right:

```
$('a').each( function() {
  var str = $(this).html();
  str = str.replace('Topic from url', 'Topic from URL');
  $(this).html(str);
});
```

I admit that the javascript solution is far from pretty, but it solves the build time problem pretty well.

Note that Jekyll is pretty slow. I would advice you to dig into Hugo if you require faster build times.

Comment: Oh, very manual ;) Looks like the href could be adapted (`/{{ path }}/{{ topic }}` would be enough in my case) and replace part of my "workaround". But I wanted to get the actual `title` property from the `topic.md` automatically as well... (So link text should not be "Topic" but "This is the page title defined in topic,md")

Comment: You could loop over the site.pages and match the url to find this title... but that would (dramatically) increase build time. I would not do that as it seems not really necessary to me.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping there was a (performant) "give me the title for this file/page" functionality I didn't know about.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, based on JoostS code:

````
{% assign  url = page.url | remove:'.html' | split: "/"  %}
{% assign path = url | pop %}
{% if path.size == 1 %}
    <a class="back" href="/home/">home</a>
{% else %}
    <a class="back" href="/{% for dir in path offset: 1 %}{{ dir | append: "/" }}{% endfor %}">{{ path | last }}</a>
{% endif %}```
````