# Counting loop value in jekyll schema breadcrumb list

Tags: jekyll, liquid, jekyll-theme

This question is related to [What are some good ways to implement breadcrumbs on a Jekyll site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612235/what-are-some-good-ways-to-implement-breadcrumbs-on-a-jekyll-site) and I need to get the position from the loop. **`<meta itemprop="position" content="">`**

```
<nav class="breadcrumbs bootstrap hidden-sm-down">
<ol class="breadcrumb list-unstyled" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
 <li class="breadcrumb-item" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><a itemprop="item" href="/"><span itemprop="name">Home</span></a><meta itemprop="position" content="1"></li>
 {% assign crumbs = page.url | split: '/' %}
 {% assign crumbs_total = crumbs | size | minus: 1 %}
   {% for crumb in crumbs offset: 1 %}
    {% if forloop.index == crumbs_total %}
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active"itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><meta itemprop="item" content="{{ site.url }}{{ page.url | relative_url }}"><span itemprop="name">{{ page.crumbtitle }}</span><meta itemprop="position" content=""></li>
    {% else %}
        <li class="breadcrumb-item" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><a itemprop="item" href="{% assign crumb_limit = forloop.index | plus: 1 %}{% for crumb in crumbs limit: crumb_limit %}{{ crumb | append: '/' }}{% endfor %}"><span itemprop="name">{{ crumb | replace:'-',' ' | upcase }}</span></a><meta itemprop="position" content=""></li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ol>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On **line #12** Just add one. `<meta itemprop="position" content="{{ crumbs_total | plus:1 }}">`
**Line # 16** already has the var, `{% assign crumb_limit = forloop.index | plus: 1 %}`
So, on **line # 18** you only need `<meta itemprop="position" content="{{ crumb_limit }}">`

```
{% if page.layout != 'home' %}
<nav class="breadcrumbs bootstrap hidden-sm-down">
<ol class="breadcrumb list-unstyled" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
 <li class="breadcrumb-item" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><a itemprop="item" href="/"><span itemprop="name">Home</span></a><meta itemprop="position" content="1"></li>
 {% assign crumbs = page.url | split: '/' %}
 {% assign crumbs_total = crumbs | size | minus: 1 %}
    {% for crumb in crumbs offset: 1 %}
    {% if forloop.index == crumbs_total %}
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active"itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><meta itemprop="item" content="{{ site.url }}{{ page.url | relative_url }}"><span itemprop="name">{{ page.crumbtitle }}</span><meta itemprop="position" content="{{ crumbs_total | plus:1 }}"></li>
    {% else %}
{% assign crumbs_position = 1 %}
        <li class="breadcrumb-item" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><a itemprop="item" href="{% assign crumb_limit = forloop.index | plus: 1 %}{% for crumb in crumbs limit: crumb_limit %}{{ crumb | append: '/' }}{% endfor %}"><span itemprop="name">{{ crumb | replace:'-',' ' | upcase }}</span></a>{% assign crumbs_postion = crumbs_position | plus:1 %}<meta itemprop="position" content="{{ crumb_limit }}"></li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ol>
</nav>
{% endif %}
```